# Setting TTL value in android push notification through PHP

Tags: php, android, push-notification, ttl

I can send push notification through PHP but what I want to know is how would I set the TTL value for same ?

This is the code:

```
<?php

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'My API key' );

$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] ); 
$msg = array
(
'message'   => 'msg',
'title'     => 'title',
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon');

$fields = array( 
'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
'data'  => $msg );

$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

?>
```

Couldn't find a way to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just add ttl like this:

```
$fields = array(
        'app_id' => $AppID,
        'included_segments' => array('All'),
        'headings' => $heading,
        'contents' => $content,
        'filters' => $Filters,
        'ttl' => $seconds
    );
```